# Posso dire 'ti prego' invece di 'per favore'?

Tags: single-words

Io finora usavo l'espressione **ti prego** come sostituto di **per favore**. Queste due espressioni hanno lo stesso significato?

Comment: *Ti prego* is much stronger, it means *I beg you* rather than *please*.

Comment: Somebody should mention that just *prego* is in use as a more formal version of *per favore* (especially in some fixed expressions such as *Attendere, prego*). And that, as an equivalent to *per favore*, one can use *per piacere*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a normal occasion, in everyday life, you will always use "per favore".
As @Denis Nardin commented,"ti prego" is a much more stronger word. You would use it in a more urgent and desperate situation. Usually, when you need quick help or in dangerous situation , is "ti prego" much more used and people react differently, since they get that the situation is more serious.

Nella vita quotidiana, normalmente si usa l'espressione "per favore".
"Ti prego" o "la prego" vengono usate in situazioni più importanti o in situazioni in qui si ha bisogno di ricevere attenzione. Le persone reagiscono differentemente al "per favore" e al "ti prego".